# Rounded edges of 3d cube

Tags: css

I have created a 3D cube. I want the edges of the cube to be smooth and curved - not sharp.

```css
.wrap {
    perspective: 800px;
    perspective-origin: 50% 100px;
}

.cube {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.cube div {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #aaa;
}

.back {
    transform: translateZ(-100px) rotateY(180deg);
}

.right {
    transform: rotateY(-270deg) translateX(100px);
    transform-origin: top right;
}

.left {
    transform: rotateY(270deg) translateX(-100px);
    transform-origin: center left;
}

.top {
    transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateY(-100px);
    transform-origin: top center;
}

.bottom {
    transform: rotateX(90deg) translateY(100px);
    transform-origin: bottom center;
}

.front {
    transform: translateZ(100px);
}

@keyframes spin {
    from {
        transform: rotateY(0);
    }

    to {
        transform: rotateY(360deg);
    };
}

.cube {
    animation: spin 5s infinite linear;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="cube">
    <div class="front">front</div>
    <div class="back">back</div>
    <div class="top">top</div>
    <div class="bottom">bottom</div>
    <div class="left">left</div>
    <div class="right">right</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I get this:
http://jsfiddle.net/jaap/54juW/
Is this how far you are as well?

Comment: @Jaap Incidentally, that doesn't work on Chrome.

Comment: LOL, didn't even think of ignoring Chrome... I see it running in FF now ;) Thanks Scott

Comment: use border-radius at '.cube div'

Comment: @nkmol i want to create curved edges not the corners of the cubes.

Comment: sorry guys, my bad just add background color in class .cube div for seeing how it looks.

Comment: With colors and opacity to see what's happening:  http://jsfiddle.net/54juW/3/

Comment: how about use webgl to do the whole 3d effects, performance is better and you can make the whole thing in javascript

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no 'easy' way to do this. You will have to make 5+ 'edges' for each 'join' and position them at the proper angles around those corners. Then the Corners are going to be fairly complex.[image]

Consider that each 'facet' of this wireframe would need to be its own dom element.

Comment: ok got the basic idea of doing this but can you please provide me some more reference for doing this.

Comment: You are going to have to do some math. I don't know of any example of this floating around out there in CSS3 space. You could consider using a tool like [this](http://tridiv.com/) to help you along.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, a bit updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/54juW/2/

Adding border radius is not what you're looking for I think?

```
border-radius: 40px;
```

Making smooth corners however is hard to achieve i think.
Maybe you could add more sides in the corner and not flipping them 90 degrees at once but have several smaller "sides" which you flip very little each time.

Another article which does something like to get a bit of a dice effect (not really nice if you ask me, but maybe a look in the right direction)

http://cssnerd.com/2012/02/26/css-3d-cube-dice/

Comment: thanx i have seen it... But this isn't exact what i want to do. i want to achieve edges as in the image below provide by @fresheyeball.

Answer (score 1):

This is the best one I found, pure CSS rolling dice (a rounded cube):

https://codepen.io/tameraydin/pen/CADvB

Copying it here, in case something happens to Codepen:

```js
// MIT licensed, © 2015 Tamer Aydn https://codepen.io/tameraydin
```

```css
body {
  font-size:.9em;
  font-family:sans-serif;
}
@keyframes spin {
    0% { transform: translateZ(-100px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg); }
    16% { transform: translateZ(-100px) rotateX(180deg) rotateY(180deg) rotateZ(0deg); }
    33% { transform: translateZ(-100px) rotateX(360deg) rotateY(90deg) rotateZ(180deg); }
    50% { transform: translateZ(-100px) rotateX(360deg) rotateY(360deg) rotateZ(360deg); }
    66% { transform: translateZ(-100px) rotateX(180deg) rotateY(360deg) rotateZ(270deg); }
    83% { transform: translateZ(-100px) rotateX(270deg) rotateY(180deg) rotateZ(180deg); }
    100% { transform: translateZ(-100px) rotateX(360deg) rotateY(360deg) rotateZ(360deg); }
}
@keyframes spin-duplicate {
    0% { transform: translateZ(-100px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg); }
    16% { transform: translateZ(-100px) rotateX(180deg) rotateY(180deg) rotateZ(0deg); }
    33% { transform: translateZ(-100px) rotateX(360deg) rotateY(90deg) rotateZ(180deg); }
    50% { transform: translateZ(-100px) rotateX(360deg) rotateY(360deg) rotateZ(360deg); }
    66% { transform: translateZ(-100px) rotateX(180deg) rotateY(360deg) rotateZ(270deg); }
    83% { transform: translateZ(-100px) rotateX(270deg) rotateY(180deg) rotateZ(180deg); }
    100% { transform: translateZ(-100px) rotateX(360deg) rotateY(360deg) rotateZ(360deg); }
}
@keyframes roll {
    0% { transform: translate3d(-200px,-50px,-400px) }
    12% { transform: translate3d(0px,0,-100px) }
    25% { transform: translate3d(200px,-50px,-400px) }
    37% { transform: translate3d(0px,-100px,-800px) }
    50% { transform: translate3d(-200px,-50px,-400px) }
    62% { transform: translate3d(0px,0,-100px) }
    75% { transform: translate3d(200px,-50px,-400px) }
    87% { transform: translate3d(0px,-100px,-800px) }
    100% { transform: translate3d(-200px,-50px,-400px) }
}
#roll:checked ~ #platform > #dice {
    animation: spin-duplicate 2s infinite linear;
}
#roll:checked ~ #platform {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    animation: roll 1.6s infinite linear;
}
#secondroll:checked ~ #roll:checked ~ #platform > #dice,
#secondroll:checked ~ #roll:checked ~ #platform {
    animation-play-state: paused;
}
#wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    padding-top: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    perspective: 1200px;
}
#platform {
  margin-top:100px;
}
#dice span {
    position:absolute;
    margin:100px 0 0 100px;
    display: block;
    font-size: 2.5em;
    padding: 10px;
}
#dice {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    animation: spin 50s infinite linear;
}
.side {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow:inset 0 0 40px #ccc;
    border-radius: 40px;
}
#dice .cover, #dice .inner {
    background: #e0e0e0;
    box-shadow: none;
}
#dice .cover {
    border-radius: 0;
    transform: translateZ(0px);
}
#dice .cover.x {
    transform: rotateY(90deg);
}
#dice .cover.z {
    transform: rotateX(90deg);
}
#dice .front  {
    transform: translateZ(100px);
}
#dice .front.inner  {
    transform: translateZ(98px);
}
#dice .back {
    transform: rotateX(-180deg) translateZ(100px);
}
#dice .back.inner {
    transform: rotateX(-180deg) translateZ(98px);
}
#dice .right {
    transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(100px);
}
#dice .right.inner {
    transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(98px);
}
#dice .left {
    transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(100px);
}
#dice .left.inner {
    transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(98px);
}
#dice .top {
    transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(100px);
}
#dice .top.inner {
    transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(98px);
}
#dice .bottom {
    transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(100px);
}
#dice .bottom.inner {
    transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(98px);
}
.dot {
    position:absolute;
    width:46px;
    height:46px;
    border-radius:23px;
    background:#444;
    box-shadow:inset 5px 0 10px #000;
}
.dot.center {
    margin:77px 0 0 77px;
}
.dot.dtop {
    margin-top:20px;
}
.dot.dleft {
    margin-left:134px;
}
.dot.dright {
    margin-left:20px;
}
.dot.dbottom {
    margin-top:134px;
}
.dot.center.dleft {
    margin:77px 0 0 20px;
}
.dot.center.dright {
    margin:77px 0 0 134px;
}

#background {
 position:fixed;
 z-index:-1;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 background: #071a1e;
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #071a1e 0%, #274249 100%);
 background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#071a1e), color-stop(100%,#274249));
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #071a1e 0%,#274249 100%);
 background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #071a1e 0%,#274249 100%);
}
label, input[type=checkbox]:before {
 position: absolute;
 overflow:hidden;
 top:40px;
 left:40px;
 display:block;
 width:120px;
 padding-top:9px;
 height:31px;
 cursor:pointer;
 text-align:center;
 font-size:1.2em;
 font-weight:bold;
 color:#fff;
 border-radius:6px;
 border:1px solid;
}
input[type=checkbox]:before {
 background:transparent;
 border-color:transparent;
}
input[type=checkbox] {
 display:none;
}
label {
 opacity:.5;
 transition:all .3s ease;
}
label:hover {
 opacity:1;
 box-shadow:0 0 18px rgba(255,255,255,.5);
}
label[for=roll] {
 z-index:1;
 text-shadow:0 -1px 0 #006699;
 border-color:#17C7EC;
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0099CC 0%, #006699 100%);
 background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#0099CC), color-stop(100%,#006699));
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0099CC 0%,#006699 100%);
 background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0099CC 0%,#006699 100%);
}
label[for=secondroll] {
 margin-top:-100px;
 text-shadow:0 -1px 0 #CC0033;
 border-color:#FF8298;
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FF6666 0%, #CC0033 100%);
 background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#FF6666), color-stop(100%,#CC0033));
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FF6666 0%,#CC0033 100%);
 background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FF6666 0%,#CC0033 100%);
}
#roll:checked ~ label[for=roll] {
 margin-top:-100px;
}
#roll:checked ~ label[for=secondroll] {
 margin-top:0px;
}
#secondroll:checked ~ label[for=secondroll] {
 text-shadow:0 -1px 0 #336633;
 border-color:#66FF99;
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #66CC66 0%, #336633 100%);
 background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#66CC66), color-stop(100%,#336633));
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #66CC66 0%,#336633 100%);
 background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #66CC66 0%,#336633 100%);
}
#secondroll:checked ~ label[for=secondroll] span {
 display:none;
}
#secondroll:checked ~ label[for=secondroll]:after {
 content:"Keep rollin'!";
}
```

```html
<div id="background"></div>
<div id="wrapper">
  <input id="secondroll" name="roll" type="checkbox">
  <input id="roll" name="roll" type="checkbox">
  <label for="roll">Roll it!</label>
  <label for="secondroll"><span>Stop!</span></label>
  <div id="platform">
    <div id="dice">
      <div class="side front">
        <div class="dot center"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="side front inner"></div>
      <div class="side top">
        <div class="dot dtop dleft"></div>
        <div class="dot dbottom dright"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="side top inner"></div>
      <div class="side right">
        <div class="dot dtop dleft"></div>
        <div class="dot center"></div>
        <div class="dot dbottom dright"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="side right inner"></div>
      <div class="side left">
        <div class="dot dtop dleft"></div>
        <div class="dot dtop dright"></div>
        <div class="dot dbottom dleft"></div>
        <div class="dot dbottom dright"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="side left inner"></div>
      <div class="side bottom">
        <div class="dot center"></div>
        <div class="dot dtop dleft"></div>
        <div class="dot dtop dright"></div>
        <div class="dot dbottom dleft"></div>
        <div class="dot dbottom dright"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="side bottom inner"></div>
      <div class="side back">
        <div class="dot dtop dleft"></div>
        <div class="dot dtop dright"></div>
        <div class="dot dbottom dleft"></div>
        <div class="dot dbottom dright"></div>
        <div class="dot center dleft"></div>
        <div class="dot center dright"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="side back inner"></div>
      <div class="side cover x"></div>
      <div class="side cover y"></div>
      <div class="side cover z"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's very cool, but *why* does it work?